# Is there a technique in SQL to restrict a user to see the result of an aggregate but not the individual rows comprising it?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am asking for ideas on a technique or approach in general. For the sake of argument, let's say BigQuery is the platform.

I have a table with the following data:

| Identity | Records |
| --- | --- |
| abc123 | 30 |
| abc124 | 50 |
| abc125 | 53 |

I don't want anyone to see the individual values in the Identity column. But I want them to be able to perform a distinct count on the column, and see the result. E.g.

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Identity) as COUNT_Identities
, SUM(Records) AS SUM_Records

Which would return

| COUNT_Identities | SUM_Records |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 133 |

In effect, I want to permit the user to execute aggregated queries only. Does anyone know if there is a way to do this?

I've looked into row and column-level security, but this doesn't seem to apply to what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the different hash functions available in bigquery.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/hash_functions

For example, you can create a view hashing whatever columns you want to encrypt and then provide access to only that view, protecting the actual table and therefore the raw data.

This will allow any user with access to that view to perform any query without having access to actual data.

Comment: This is a great answer - although for me it wouldn't work (I think) because I omitted something from my question. Which is, that a hash of the identity could still be used to identify that row (and any other rows with the same identity) because the hash would be the same for the same string of characters.

In essence, the actual Identity string itself does not carry sensitive information; the issue is preventing rows with the same identity from being associated. Under this regime, I just want the user to be able to count the number of identities.

Comment: There is no way then to expose the actual data to be queried/aggregated without something to aggregate on (same values).

The only solution I can imagine is to create views with the aggregation metrics already cooked.